# DELETE QUERY Runs Slow First Time, but second time onwards (for same condition) runs fast - How to make the query fast at first time running?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider Table:

```
Table Name:ORDER
Columns: (ID (PK), ORDER_NUM, ORDER_STATUS, etc...)
Index(ORDER_IDX) exists on (ORDER_NUM, ORDER_STATUS) together.
There are various FKs too, on which Indexes exist as well.
There are about 2 million rows in the table.
```

Consider SQL Query:

```
DELETE from ORDER where ORDER_NUM=234234;
```

For a particular ORDER_NUM value, the DELETE Query runs very slow first time (almost 5 seconds to delete 200 rows).

But if I rollback and run DELETE Query again for **same** ORDER_NUM, the DELETE QUERY now runs in 200 milliseconds.

Therefore, for ANY **new** ORDER_NUM supplied to this query - the query runs very slow.

**What can I do to fasten the query first time itself? Do I have to rebuild indexes? Or anything else?**

*I am testing this from a Oracle SQL Client Tool (like TOAD/SQL-Developer) - after seeing this slow behavior within the web application where it is actually used.*

**EDIT>>>**
***Results of SET AUTOTRACE ON***

**FIRST TIME when QUERY is RUN**

```
           3  user calls
           0  physical read total multi block requests
     4915200  physical read total bytes
     4915200  cell physical IO interconnect bytes
           0  commit cleanout failures: block lost
           0  IMU commits
           1  IMU Flushes
           0  IMU contention
           0  IMU bind flushes
           0  IMU mbu flush
```

**SECOND TIME When Query is RUN**

```
           3  user calls
           0  physical read total multi block requests
           0  physical read total bytes
           0  cell physical IO interconnect bytes
           0  commit cleanout failures: block lost
           0  IMU commits
           1  IMU Flushes
           0  IMU contention
           0  IMU bind flushes
           0  IMU mbu flush
```

**The EXPLAIN Plans** - in both FIRST and SECOND RUN is exactly same - shown below:

```
    ID     OPERATION          NAME       ROWS    Bytes    Cost(%CPU)     Time<br>
=======================================================================================
    0      DELETE Statement               49     2891     41   (0)       00:00:01
    1      DELETE             ORDER      
    2      INDEX RANGE SCAN   ORDER_IDX   49     2891     3    (0)       00:00:01
```

You can see Very High Physical Reads, during the First Time.
Can I do anything at all to help with this situation?

Comment: cacheable data ? when you redo - they are still there - in memory
the other problem is to many splits in index cluster - needs to be reorganised ....

Comment: @jasper:insert 200 rows commit and then run this command `ANALYZE TABLE <TABLE_NAME> COMPUTE STATISTICS;`  and then delete the records .Now check whats the time it take to delete

Comment: @GauravSoni That did not help. We are using Oracle 11g by the way.

Comment: Simon probably has the answer (your data is now cached), but you need to show the execution plan for this statement. Also, are there any triggers on this table? Are you using Exadata? Do you have any `on delete cascade` FKs referencing this table?

Comment: How many rows does this query delete?  What exactly is the explain plan?  Is it using the index, is it using a range scan or a full index scan, etc?  And is the explain plan the same the first and second time you run the query?  There are several things that may change the plan after the first run.  Do you use a bind variable for ORDER_NUM?

Comment: Explain Plans are exactly same in both First and Second Time. They use Index.

Comment: Please post the explain plans! Also, are there any triggers on the table you're deleting from?

Comment: jonearles> This query deletes about 300 rows. Chris> Added Explain Plans

Comment: The first query does physical reads, the second execution doesn't. That is the answer to the question - the data is cached.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

This may be caused by table/index fragmentation, and as you are accessing data through an index, more likely index.

For table level, you would need both of the following steps, for index only (2):

(1) Deal with the table fragmentation: `alter table "ORDER" move`

(2) Rebuild indexes: `alter index "<YourIndex>" rebuild`

If you are doing a lot of deletes & inserts, or updates that cause row migrations, this could apply to you.

Comment: i rebuilt the index - that did not help. (not yet done a table move though). Pls see the SET AUTOTRACE ON results - i have added in Question.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to rebuild the indexes again after doing the move. Also what extent sizes (initial & next) are you using for this table? And also, is ORDER_NUM unique, and are there any foreign keys which reference this table?

Comment: This is very unlikely to help. Table fragmentation is really not an issue, and rebuilding indexes only provides temporary relief of the issue until the index grows to it's normal size. In the case of an index on a column like ORDER_NUM, which is likely to be an increasing value, the index is probably already quite compact.

Comment: Thanks @muhmud, problem appears to be with TABLE FRAGMENTATION, i am getting much better results now after doing 'TABLE MOVE' and 'INDEX REBUILD'. I will continue with more testing and report back any new findings as well.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - Table fragmentation can be a very real issue on heaps that are inserted & deleted from frequently. Also, for the index, if ORDER_NUM is an incrementing number, when rows for an old ORDER_NUM are deleted, they would never be filled in by a new value, due to the ordered nature of indexes, hence leading to internal fragmentation. Are you sure you understand these concepts?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean by "table fragmentation" then, before we know if we're talking about the same concepts, because in a heap table the deletion of rows makes space for new rows to be inserted in those blocks, and emptied index leaf blocks are also re-used. @Simon has the correct answer to this question -- this table move has just cached the blocks for both deletes.

Comment: @Jasper your problem is nothing to do with table fragmentation. The autotrace shows the issue with physical reads, and when you have just moved the table the blocks have been cached, hence a fast first and second delete.

Comment: An emptied index block would be reused, but not a partially empty one, lol! Also, in a table, space can only be reused when a page can fit new rows. If it can't, the space can't be, leading to 'holes'. As the fundamental unit of I/O is a page, you could end up reading more pages than you have to in order to satisfy a request, hence more physical I/O then necessary, and worse cache efficiency. With updates, and the introduction of forward pointers, the problem can get even worse. @Jasper - could you tell us how long ago you did the move & rebuild?

Comment: If a block cannot fit new rows then moving the table is not going to change that -- if PCTFREE is set too high then it can be reduced, of course. Yes, a partially emptied leaf block cannot be reused, but where's the part where you analysed whether that (or the unfilled table blocks) were a significant problem, or explained how they made the first table run quickly and the second run slowly? Just advising people to throw table moves and index rebuilds at their system is frankly irresponsible, and the arguments against it have been very well-established.

Comment: If a block cannot fit new rows, then moving it *can* help, because the sum of space available on the page can be used to fit the rows. If there are two slots on a page that in total will fit a new row, oracle will not shift the rows around on the page during an insert. In the case of a fragmented table the behaviour you would see from first access to second would match what what @Jasper was experiencing, hence my answer. Frankly, I think you need to calm down a little, dear.

Comment: Jasper is simply seeing the effect of caching, nothing more. It's Oracle 101, and that's why Simon's answer is currently +12 and yours is -3.

Comment: Well, at least you've got nothing more to say about fragmentation! Also, I think the score is simply you starting a ripple effect.

Comment: I'd be willing to look at any material you have that supports the claim that "If there are two slots on a page that in total will fit a new row, oracle will not shift the rows around on the page during an insert". I don't believe that is the case because it implies that the ASSM state of the block (or presence on the freelist) is affected by inter-row space availability, not the total block space availability, and it would be an obvious problem that kernel development could have addressed.

Comment: OK, so the oracle documentation (docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/…), in the section on coalescing free space, says that this would be handled transparently by the engine under specific circumstances, which cover the scenario of the insert. However, the effect of updates where space is not available on the page still leads to fragmentation through a row migration and forward pointer being created, for which a table move would help. I've added a little something to the answer to reflect this.

Comment: So it does happen in both inserts and updates -- in other words, whenever it's needed. You should reflect on your previous certainty that this was not how Oracle works. Row migrations are easily cataloguoed with ANALYZE TABLE ... LIST CHAINED ROWS, but you didn't advise Jasper to do that. Bottom line -- I'm afraid that your professional ego has led you to defend an incorrect position, and persist in trying to justify an obviously ioncorrect answer. I'm out of here -- last word to you if you like.

Comment: The question whether this is cause by a "*bad*" index can only be answered by looking at the trace files.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - I think you should reflect on your own uncertainty about how this works, and stop trying to bulldoze your way into a discussion. Even though free space is coalesced for certain insert/updates, this doesn't mean that fragmentation cannot cause this type of problem. Thinking about this, I think that it probably *is* because free space fragments are being reused, and rows for an ORDER_NUM are being dispersed across many pages that this problem is occurring. After a move, new rows would go in at the end of the table, in less pages, and so give a better I/O profile.

Comment: Minus 9. The audience has spoken.

Answer (score 17):

The key to understand your problem is to understand how statements are executed. DELETE is a relatively expensive operation and often leads to performance problems. So here is how Oracle executes a DML statement:

1. The first step in executing DML is to find the required blocks in the database buffer cache (if they are already there) or copy them into the buffer cache from the datafiles (slow). In addition to that, an empty block of an undo segment is also copied into the buffer cache.
2. Then, locks are placed on the affected rows and indices.
3. After that, redo is generated: Change vectors describing all the changes done to the data block and undo block are generated. For a DELETE, the change vector to be written to the undo block is the entire row.
4. Then, the DELETE is carried out. The whole row is copied from the data block to the undo block and the row in the data block is deleted. DELETE generates much more undo data than an INSERT for example, because the contents of the whole row are copied (so other sessions can read the original data or the deletion can be rolled back).

Your query almost certainly runs faster the second time **because all the relevant blocks are already in the database buffer cache**. Of course, the more blocks can be held in the database buffer cache, the less I/O is needed. **Make sure your SGA is sized appropriately.**

So for your problem, we have to look at the following points:

- Most importantly, **does your query use your index?** Is the index VALID? Run the EXPLAIN PLAN for your DELETE query and check if the index for ORDER_NUM is used and how your data is accessed.
- Are there any **CONSTRAINTS** on the table? If there are CONSTRAINTS with "ON DELETE CASCADE", there might be other tables affected by your DELETE.

So for your problem, looking at the Execution Plan (EXPLAIN PLAN) might be your best bet.

Comment: Simon> How can i check if my SGA is sized properly? Anything i need to look at Table Level?  The EXPLAIN PLAN results, and CONSTRAINT are the things i looked at first - they are fine. My main question is: First time DELETE takes almost 5 seconds, and next time onwards same delete (as long as condition remains same) takes just 200 milliseconds. What can i do to improve this situation. Thanks

Comment: First, find out how big your database is. How big are your most accessed tables? Since you have current statistics, it's easiest to use `select bytes/1024/1024 mb from dba_segments where owner='SIMON';` or similar. Then, look at `v$sga` to check how big your SGA is. In the best case, the "Database Buffers" are bigger than your data, but that is not always applicable. As mentioned above, the second time you execute that query, all affected blocks are already in memory (the database buffer cache) and can therefore be deleted almost instantly. That is the reason the second query executes so fast.

Comment: Thanks - i have added SET AUTOTRACEON Results.

Comment: Art> How do u make the query run fast, the first time is the question here. Thanks

Comment: @Jasper that's not what the title of the question says, you are asking for the why.

Comment: Sizing of the SGA would be better tackled with the buffer cache advice rather than estimates based on database size, I think http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/memory.htm#i45097

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the issue of buffer caching, one way of improving performance would be to promote physical clustering of the records that have the same ORDER_NUM. This would make sense only if you most commonly select groups of records by the ORDER_NUM, but could be achieved by creating the table in a hash cluster (along with any child tables that also contain the ORDER_NUM).

The benefit would be that a query with an ORDER_NUM predicate would access fewer blocks of the  table segment, so even if physical i/o is required you would need less of it. Furthermore, you would be making more efficient use of the buffer cache by ensuring that each cached block contains a higher proportion of rows that you're interested in, and you'd be caching fewer blocks.

Comment: Curious to be down-voted without a comment on the rationale for it.

Comment: This seems a bit over the top to solve this problem, i.e. completely redesigning the storage layer, in a fairly complex way.

Comment: The particular problem here is to understand why the first delete is slower than the second, and it does not have a direct solution, just an explanation -- it's a matter of whether the blocks are cached or not (@Simon's answer). If the performance of a 300 row delete is a problem for the application then the solution is more efficient caching, or more efficient storage to reduce the need for caching. I provide this as a possible way of implementing such a solution. Others solutions are possible -- adjusting the cache size, for example -- but the cluster implementation is very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

> "You can see Very High Physical Reads, during the First Time.  Can i do anything at all help with this situation?"

Your query has to locate the records before it can zap them.  If the records are in memory that's fast, if they're on disk that will be *orders of magnitude* slower.  [Find out more.](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html)  So that's what is happening.  The first time you read the rows physically and that's slow, but now the rows are in the DB buffer cache so subsequent reads are faster.

What can you do to improve the performance of the first read?  Well that depends on where the time goes.  Despite several people asking you have not provided [the explain plans](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9010.htm#i2061796). Without knowing the access paths there's not much concrete advice we can give you.  So here's a couple of pointers.

`physical read total multi block requests` is zero so all the `physical read total bytes` represents single block i.e. index reads.  That this takes a long time suggests the index might be a poor one.  One thing to check is the clustering factor of the index: if the clustering factor is close to the number of blocks index range scans will be pretty fast.  Probably the index your delete is using has a poor clustering factor.  That's why you need the explain plan: so you can investigate the quality of the index.  Read this article by Tom Kyte to [find out more about index clustering](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52asktom-1735913.html).

If your query has a poor clustering factor there is a limit to how much you can tune it.  You can't polish the proverbial.  Deletion requires the retrieval of the whole row, so you have to read the table.  So perhaps the simplest option is just to speed up the table read:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;

delete /*+ no_index (orders) 
           parallel */
from orders
where order_num=234234;
```

You're using 11g so you don't need to specify [the object in the PARALLEL hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50801).  Note you do need Enterprise Edition for parallel operations.